# refresh partial popup with new data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a partial that displays a table and has backend pagination.  The pagination looks like:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(">>", "EventHistory", "Event", new { id = ViewBag.EventId, page = ViewBag.Page+1 }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET" })
```

which calls:

```
public ActionResult EventHistory(int id, int page = 1)
    {
        var viewModel = eventService.GetHistory(id, page);
        ViewBag.EventId = id;
        ViewBag.Page = page;
        return PartialView("History", viewModel);
    }
```

When debugging I can see that the viewModel has the proper data in it, but the partial popup does not update with the new data.  How can I refresh or update the partial with the correct data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [AjaxOptions properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions_properties%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
new AjaxOptions { 
   HttpMethod = "GET", 
   InsertionMode = "Replace", // the mode that specifies how to insert the response into the target DOM element.
   UpdateTargetId = "ContainerId", //sets the ID of the DOM element to update by using the response from the server
}
```